# Spring Boot @ResponseBody Jackson - escape all String fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

Is there any way to configure Jackson in Spring Boot so I can HTML escape all the values in the @RequestBody? I have tried with serializers but as far as I know they are defined to a specific class. I would need a filter which process all the values sent in the JSON and escape them with something like:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(value)
```

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a really really bad idea. Why would you do that?If someone sends some text, then store that text. If you display this text inside an HTML page, then escape it before displaying it. If it needs to be displayed in some other way inside a rich client not using HTML for example), display it as is: you really don't want to unescape it.

Comment: @JBNizet I do not have any UI consuming my API, it is all machine to machine. The whole point is preventing XSS attacks. How would you prevent your backend from those attacks? And, even if it would be a bad idea which I think it is not, anybody with the answer?

Comment: If the text is never displayed anywhere, how could you possibly have an XSS attack? And if it is, then html-escape the text when it's being displayed in an html page. Xml-escape it if it's being used in an XML document. Don't escape it at all if it's being used in a rich application, etc. etc.

Comment: You can inject XSS when Man in the Middle. You do not want to store scripts in database. Actually most of the tools for detecting vulnerabilities in APIs will spot it straightaway.

Comment: So what? If you escape when you *display* the text, what's the problem? See https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1032029 for example: do you see how the body column contains unescaped HTML mrkup? Do you really think StackOverflow has an XSS problem?

Comment: Well, I guess OWASP thinks otherwise about not escaping in the backend but only in the frontend; https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#you-need-a-security-encoding-library As I said, multiple tools raise these kind of vulnerabilities as high risk ones.

Comment: OWASP doesn't think otherwise at all. The article you linked to says : *This article treats an HTML page like a template, with slots where a developer is allowed to put untrusted data [...] RULE #1 - HTML Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Element Content*. So, it escapes the untrusted data **before displaying it inside an HTML template**. Not when the text is received from the user.

Comment: The first example it contains is: `<body>
...ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA BEFORE PUTTING HERE...
</body>`. See: the untrusted data is escaped before putting it in the HTML template. Not when it's received in the request body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192023/discussion-between-alvgarvilla-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 2):

How about creating an XSS filter and invoke it in RequestInterceptor

```
public class XSSRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

public XSSRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
}

/**
 * Get XSS stripped parameter values
 * @param parameter parameter values string to be checked
 * @return xss striped encoded string
 */
@Override
public String[] getParameterValues(String parameter)
{
    String[] values = super.getParameterValues(parameter);
    if(values == null)
    {
        return new String[0];
    }
    int count = values.length;
    String[] encodedValues = new String[count];
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        encodedValues[i]= stripXSS(values[i]);
    }
    return encodedValues;
}

/**
 * Get XSS stripped parameter
 * @param parameter parameter string to be checked
 * @return xss striped encoded string
 */
@Override
public String getParameter(String parameter)
{
    String value = super.getParameter(parameter);
    return stripXSS(value);
}

/**
 * Get XSS stripped header
 * @param name header string to be checked
 * @return xss striped encoded string
 */
@Override
public String getHeader(String name)
{
    String value = super.getHeader(name);
    return stripXSS(value);
}

private String stripXSS(String value)
{
    return HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(value);
}
}
```

XSS filter as below

```
 @WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
 public class XSSFilter implements Filter {


/**
 * Filter initialization
 * @param filterConfig FilterConfig
*/
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    // nothing required here
}

/**
 * Actual filter implementation
 * @param servletRequest ServletRequest
 * @param servletResponse ServletResponse
 * @param filterChain FilterChain
 * @throws IOException IOException
 * @throws ServletException ServletException
 */
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    filterChain.doFilter(new XSSRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest), servletResponse);
}

/**
 * Filter destroy
 */
@Override
public void destroy() {
    // nothing required here
}
}
```