# How to prevent XSS attacks or untrusted data in Rest API JSON using Java?

Tags: java, rest, api, grails

I had developed a Rest API application and have handled Authentication and Authorization using custom JWT.
I want to further make the application secure from XSS attacks or validation for untrusted data which could be handled for each and every field of JSON request.

Can I get some help in this regard so that efficient data processing will happen at the entry-level of the request without touching internal business validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to override the HttpServletRequest in a Servlet Filter(if you are using Servlet).

1. Extends HttpServletRequestWrapper that stores JSON body(intention is to sanitize JSON body).
2. Strip/ escape the eligible JSON value

**Extented "HttpServletRequestWrapper"** :

```
public class SanitizationRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    
        public byte[] getBody() {
            return body;
        }
    
        public void setBody(byte[] body) {
            this.body = body;
        }
    
        private byte[] body;
    
        public SanitizationRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
            super(request);
            try {
                body = IOUtils.toByteArray(super.getInputStream());
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
    
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ServletInputStreamImpl(new ByteArrayInputStream(body));
        }
    
        @Override
        public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
            String enc = getCharacterEncoding();
            if (enc == null) enc = "UTF-8";
            return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream(), enc));
        }
    
        private class ServletInputStreamImpl extends ServletInputStream {
    
            private InputStream is;
    
            public ServletInputStreamImpl(InputStream is) {
                this.is = is;
            }
    
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return is.read();
            }
    
            public boolean markSupported() {
                return false;
            }
    
            public synchronized void mark(int i) {
                throw new RuntimeException(new IOException("mark/reset not supported"));
            }
    
            public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
                throw new IOException("mark/reset not supported");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Servlet filter which sanitize request body:**

```
    public class XSSSanitizeFilters implements Filter {
            @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;
            SanitizationRequestWrapper sanitizeRequest = new SanitizationRequestWrapper(request);
                if (null != sanitizeRequest.getBody()) {
                    try {
                        sanitizeJson(sanitizeRequest);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        LOG.error("Unable to Sanitize the provided JSON .");
                    }
                    arg2.doFilter(sanitizeRequest, arg1);
    
                } else {
                    arg2.doFilter(arg0, arg1);
                }       
        }
    
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    
        }
    
        private void sanitizeJson(SanitizationRequestWrapper sanitizeRequest ) throws IOException, ParseException {
                JSONParser parser= new JSONParser();
                Object obj = parser.parse(sanitizeRequest.getReader());
                 ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                Map <String, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);
                sanitizeRequest.setBody((new JSONObject(map)).toString().getBytes());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Shantimoy! This works perfectly fine for my requirement.

Comment: "You need to override the HttpServletRequest in a Servlet Filter." - The question doesn't indicate they are even using servlets.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown : Corrected! Though example is using servelet filter ,"sanitizeJson()" method can be used irrespective of servlet.

Comment: @SHANTIMOYBANERJEE: This piece of code has worked perfectly for me. I wanted to understand how does the body still has the request body stream (json) stored in it. You have used the super(request) which will pass the reference to the HttpServletRequestWrapper. As soon as we use IoUtils, internally it calls the reader() and the request body becomes empty. So in SanitizationRequestWrapper, we should not have the request body right? Is it internally using the body attribute created in SanitizationRequestWrapper when we pass the new request to doFilter() or there is something else happening here?

Comment: What if the API is consumed by a Web server providing it own XSS sanitization or a mobile app? This question is specifically about a RESTful JSON API. You shouldn't sanitize that input or output for XSS.

Answer (score 2):

You don't filter or escape data in a restful API. API's should be client agnostic. It is the clients responsibility to provide XSS protection. If the clients are doing their job appropriately you will end up with doubly escaped data. Remember potential clients can be:

- Mobile Apps
- Backend Web Servers
- Web Browsers
- Desktop Applications
- Embedded systems/ IoT

In the above only a limited number of clients and configurations are vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need XSS filter using HTMLUtils which will filter any injected script and prevent your site. Please refer my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741351/10232467 for its complete code and implementation.

Comment: This solution is good for query parameters to be passed with the request headers, however I need to strip the same in every field in the JSON body for PUT or POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

If your API doesn't accecpt any HTML Characters then you can follow the below logic.

You can Sanitize the Input Payload with EncodeHtml and Compare it with Provided Payload.

If both Sanitized Payload and Provided payload doesn't match then there exists some Html Content and straight way throw an Excpetion.

```
String unsanitizedPayload = IOUtils.toString(multiReadRequest.getReader());
String sanitizedPayload = Encode.forHtmlContent(unsanitizedPayload);

if(!unsanitizedPayload.equals(sanitizedPayload)) {
    throw new Exception("Improper Payload");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring, Spring security guarantees basic level of protection against XSS attack. You can also use

```
@SafeHtml
private String value;
```

You will also need to add org.jsoup dependency.